# What's the correct way to store `Class` object into `NSMutableArray`?

Tags: objective-c, class, nsmutablearray

The type `Class` is not look Objective-C type. So storing it into `NSMutableArray` looks need special care. What's the *correct* way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the "correct way" but can't you store it as a string?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:NSStringFromClass([yourObject class])];
[array addObject:NSStringFromClass([anotherObject class])];
```

//Later in your code.

```
id yourObject = NSClassFromString([array objectAtIndex:0UL]);
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: Hmm it looks very regular and recommendable way. But it also looks very inefficient. Do you know about its performance consideration?

Answer (score 13):

Class objects are just like other objects. You can definitely store them in a `NSMutableArray` or do things with them as you would normally do with objects (e.g. call the methods of the root class `NSObject`, like `description` and `performSelector...`, etc.) Note that the type `Class` is a generic type for pointers to class objects, similar to how the type `id` is a generic type for pointers to objects. So a value of type `Class` can also be passed as an `id`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[yourObject class]];
[array addObject:[anotherObject class]];

//Later in your code.

Class yourObject = [array objectAtIndex:0UL];
```

Answer (score -2):

Its probably slower. To be sure measure it. It's recommended to run it on the device, so you got a feel of it.

```
CFAbsoluteTime elapsedTime, startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); 
for (id object in array) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    id myObject = NSClassFromString(object);
    //Do something with your object.
}
elapsedTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime;
NSLog(@"time in seconds: %f", elapsedTime);
```